# Dynamically changing css of html tag

Tags: asp.net

I want to change the css class of html tags like div then what I have to modify in this code.

```
Here is my code:
        <script runat="server">
        void Method(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            String color=Session["color"].ToString();
            if (HyperLink1.CssClass == color)
            {
                HyperLink1.CssClass = "Red";
            }
            else
            {
                HyperLink1.CssClass = color;
            }
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: Is that C# CodeBehind code, or JavaScript client-side code?

Comment: @Alexander, I think the `runat="server"` would be the give-away

Comment: You're creating a server-side method, but what are you actually doing to **call** the method?

Comment: I wanted to hear that from OP for a reason. :-)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<script runat="server">
void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
HyperLink1.CssClass = "MyClass";
}
</script>
```

This should execute on Page Load.